# Asset pipeline not precompiling a required file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I recently added a CSS file to my Rails 3.2 app, and I'm struggling with the asset pipeline.
Currently, it says `ActionView::Template::Error (pdf.css isn't precompiled)`.

I've added a `= require pdf` to my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file.

What else is necessary?

Do I have to add `pdf.css` to `config.assets.precompile`?

If so, why? Shouldn't the `require` take care of it?

My `application.css`:

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require chosen
*= require pdf
*= require_tree ./screen
*/
```

Comment: are you requiring pdf.css explicitly somewhere in your html templates?

Comment: Yes, it's being called by a helper defined in the [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem: `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf"`

Comment: That was the problem. If you add the above as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you requiring pdf.css explicitly somewhere in your html templates?

As explained [in the official guide to the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#search-paths), every file you require explicitly in the html (outside of the manifest files) needs to be compiled by adding them to `config.assets.precompile`.

Comment: That's not strictly true. I do need to require it in my html - it's a requirement of the [wicked_pdf gem](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). Please edit and I'll accept.

Comment: the gem should have a manifest of its own? Though clearly it hasn't if it is producing this error.

Comment: The `pdf.css` file is not defined in the gem. Read [this section](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#styles) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing in your application.css (btw isn't it supposed to be application.css.scss ?) :

```
*= require_tree .
```

This should compile all the stylesheets.

Maybe you could also try a :

```
rake assets:precompile
```

It will generate the precompiled stylesheet in your public folder (well, if I'm right...). You can then know if your file is included in the process. (don't forget to delete the compiled stylesheet in development, else the browser would always load this one and none of the changes you would make after)

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what I want! There's lots of files there I don't want to go into the asset pipeline. Also, [the guide says](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) it's `application.css`: `Rails also creates a default app/assets/stylesheets/application.css file`

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error (typo) in the pdf.css file. See if you can find any missing semi colons or brackets.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `pdf.css` to `config.assets.precompile` in your `config/environments/production.rb`.

The reason for this that rails assumes that you want all your styles in one place.

This also saves space on precompile.

Example:
The following files:

- pdf.css
- screen.css
- print.css

would then all compile into `application.css`.

Comment: Have you read my answer? I know that is a solution, but I also want to understand why!

Comment: Sounds like you're using pdf.css somewhere else outside of application.css. Look at the stack trace of where ActionView::Template::Error is thrown, it will tell you where you are using pdf.css explicitely

Comment: Yep, I actually am using it outside of application.css, see my comment to my original post. Could that be the issue?

Comment: [Found it!](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#search-paths) `It is important to note that files you want to reference outside a manifest must be added to the precompile array or they will not be available in the production environment.`